# Problema com barras de ferramentas

Tags: delphi

Estou usando `TcontrolBar` para usar barras de ferramentas flutantes feitas com `TToolbar`, o alinhamento de duas das `TControlbar` é Top e Bottom, nessas eu posso localizar a barra de ferramentas onde desejar e posso movê-las sem problemas. O problema que tenho é com as `TControlbar` na esquerda e  direita (aligned alLeft e alRight) quando eu faço dock, não permitem modificar a posição das barra de ferramentas. Alguma idéia do que está acontecendo?.

É Delphi Rad Studio 10.2

Comment: Você programou para haver o *Drag&Drop* ou apenas mexeu nas propriedades? Os *parents* das `TControlBar` são todos os mesmos?  Passe por favor mais detalhes de como você está tentando fazer (código).

Comment: Só mude as propriedades.  O parent das 4 controlbars é o mesmo form.     Olha tem algum jeito de não ter o flickering nessas barras de ferramentas ?.  Não tenho nenhum codigo alem das propriedades na definição dos objetos.